# MFC: Scrollable Panel/Sub-windows containing controls

Tags: windows, mfc, scroll

Whats the best way to create a 'scrollable panel' in MFC (C++) ? In the past I have displayed different windows "attached" or "on top" of my main dialog window as a means of display different pages of an application. What I want to do this time is create a panel of controls that can be scrolled (because the virtual size of the panel is bigger than the size of the panel itself).

Can anybody recommend any good articles or tutorials on how best to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an independent scrollbar control on the side of your dialog. Respond to the messages in the dialog to move your controls. Since the child windows will crop themselves to the parent client area, feel free to move them completely off the dialog as they scroll off the page.

Comment: Thanks Mark.. I'm actually finding at the moment that my child windows are being rendered outside of the parent window area. I've checked "Clip children" on the parent window settings and the same thing is still happening. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: Aha! I forgot to change child window to a "Child" window.. I guess now the fun part will be trying to get the scroll bars working.

Comment: If there are no notification messages available for scrollbars within Classwizard.. how would I do this?

Comment: Look for WM_HSCROLL or WM_VSCROLL messages in your dialog.

Comment: If you put a scrollbar control on a dialog, will the scrollbar only work (ie. can you only change the slider position) if you implement WM_HSCROLL yourself? I would have thought that if a range was set (e.g. 0 to 100), you'd be able to slide it through 100 positions. I can call SetScrollPos( 50 ) and the slider moves to the middle.. but I can't get it to remain where I slide it to with the mouse.

Comment: I can't believe just how useless MFC really is (after 9 years of using it). I found that if I handle SB_THUMBPOSITION myself and call SetScrollPos() it does what I have expected it to. Oh well..

Comment: Now if I move the child window using SetWindowPlacement, it clips fine to the right of the parent window, but I can't place it at coordinates to the left of the parent window (negative coordinates) - the window just doesn't display. How can I display the child window so that the parent clips the left of the child window?

Answer (score 1):

If you place the controls in a `CScrollView` or a `CFormView` they will be automatically scrollable inside the view area.

Comment: Thanks for that djeidot - I'm wanting small areas to be scrollable though (ie. I'm not using CScrollView/CFormView - I have a Dialog app and I want to scroll multiple small regions (child windows) ). Cheers.